# How to work with «l10n» in firefox addons?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla

How to make the sending and receipt of the request?

Imperative that the result can be put in the variable.

[image]

**UPD:** No solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make your popup.js code async, like so:

```
let locale;
(function storageGet(name) {
  self.port.once('localeOn', name => {
    locale = name;
  })
  self.port.emit('localeEmit', name);
})();
```

Or follow [the sdk instructions on localizing html pages here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/l10n#Using_Localized_Strings_in_HTML).

Comment: How do I get a variable with the data? `var data = storageGet("alertSaveMenu"); console.log(data); console.log(locale);` Does not work.

Comment: again, this code must be async, so the sync example that you provided `var data = sotragetGet("..")` will not work

Comment: Ok, please tell me how can I get data?